# How can I generate an RFC1123 Date string, from C code (Win32)

Tags: windows, winapi

[RFC1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) defines a number of things, among them, the format of Dates to be used in internet protocols.  HTTP ([RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)) specifies that date formats must be generated in conformance with RFC1123.

It looks like this:

```
Date: Wed, 28 Apr 2010 02:31:05 GMT
```

How can I generate an RFC1123 time string from C code, running on Windows?
I don't have the use of C# and DateTime.ToString().

I know I could write the code myself, to emit timezones and day abbreviations, but I'm hoping this already exists in the Windows API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what I used:

```
static const char *DAY_NAMES[] =
  { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
static const char *MONTH_NAMES[] =
  { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };

char *Rfc1123_DateTimeNow()
{
    const int RFC1123_TIME_LEN = 29;
    time_t t;
    struct tm tm;
    char * buf = malloc(RFC1123_TIME_LEN+1);

    time(&t);
    gmtime_s(&tm, &t);

    strftime(buf, RFC1123_TIME_LEN+1, "---, %d --- %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", &tm);
    memcpy(buf, DAY_NAMES[tm.tm_wday], 3);
    memcpy(buf+8, MONTH_NAMES[tm.tm_mon], 3);

    return buf;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, but should be reasonably close:

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm *my_tm = gmtime(&t);
strftime(buffer, buf_size, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", my_tm);
puts(buffer);
```

Comment: Note that `%a` and `%b` here depends on locale, so it isn't as robust as the solution on top.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, [InternetTimeFromSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385123%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) from Wininet API.

> RFC format used. Currently, the only
>   valid format is
>   INTERNET_RFC1123_FORMAT.

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly the thing.  But, do you know - should I have any concerns about using wininet.dll from a server application?  Will it ever be the case that wininet.dll is not present?  For example, if no IE is installed on a server, will wininet.dll be missing?

Comment: Cheeso, yeah, you need wininet.dll, but its supposed to be part of Windows. If you already implement your own, may be you don't need to use that.

Answer (score 1):

More generalized example

```
std::string rfc1123_datetime( time_t time )
{
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer [80];

    timeinfo = gmtime ( &time );
    strftime (buffer,80,"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT",timeinfo);

    return buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
char    wd[4], mo[4], dn[3], tm[9], yr[5];
time_t  now;

time(&now);
sscanf(ctime(&now), "%s %s %s %s %s", wd, mo, dn, tm, yr);
sprintf((char*) http_response, "\r\nDate: %s, %s %s %s %s GMTr\n\r\n", wd, dn, mo, yr, tm);
```

actually I used ctime_r call to be thread-safe, but it works either way...